# Using "of all days"

Tags: grammar

Is this grammatically correct?

> It began on Sunday, of all days.

Or is a comma unneeded? Otherwise, it would be:

> It began on Sunday of all days.

Which would make it sound a bit awkward due to the absence of punctuation.

Comment: Either reading sounds fine to me. If you prefer to signal a pause / the associated intonation, use the comma. But what do you find in a Google search?

Answer (score 2):

**Use the comma**, or like you said, it would sound a bit awkward. The comma is there to give a pause.

The idea here is not "Sunday of all days", because that is not a thing. What would a "Sunday of all days" even mean?

***Of all things*** -- [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/of-all-things)

> used to show that you are surprised or shocked by something that someone has done or said
>
> *She gave up a promising career as a stockbroker to become a weaver, of all things.*
> *One of my mess-mates was killed by a beer barrel, of all things.*

Comment: By this argument, a comma is {virtually) mandatory in 'We sat eating snails in the garden.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't get you. Is my answer (I'm not an expert) incorrect?

Comment: If you look at examples, they seem to indicate that there is a choice here. The comma is not needed to disambiguate; I'd use it if I wanted a pause after 'Sunday', but wouldn't consider it necessary. 'Sunday' would be emphasised in reading in either case.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Fair enough. I did actually just say "use the comma... for pause"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Maybe I don't have the best words to explain stuff, which is why I usually just stick to copypasta answers under SWRs, and that is actually not a good fit for the site either.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Do you not think it would be more usual to write *We sat in the garden eating snails*.  As you present the sentence however - a usage that is more commonly spoken than written to my ears - I think that, yes, it is most clearly written with a comma.

Comment: I don't agree; [this Glosbe article](https://glosbe.com/en/en/today%20of%20all%20days) addressing the closely related _today of all days_ seems to show that the uncommaed version is preferred. The 'Friday of all days' etc variants are not _quite_ the same, but are doubtless pulled somewhat towards the no-pause rendering.